# Help with Euler Equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

> This is from my textbook.  Can someone give me a better explanation of what to do here?  What does part (a) mean, i.e., how am I supposed to write $x = ln(t)$ in terms of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$?
>
> I just don't see it.

Comment: $$
\dfrac{d}{dt} = \dfrac{dx}{dt}\dfrac{d}{dx}
$$Feels a bit cheeky to put this as an answer (though I have done far worse in the past). Do similar for the second derivative.

Comment: The second derivative part is a bit tricky.  You want to think of $\dfrac{d^2y}{dt^2} = \dfrac{d}{dt} \dfrac{dy}{dt}$.  You already know how to write the "inner" $dy/dt$  in terms of $dy/dx$ and $t$.  Use the product rule on this, and then again $\dfrac{d}{dt} = \dfrac{dx}{dt} \dfrac{d}{dx}$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks for the chain rule for the 2nd der.  I'll use the product rule from the first deritative. Much help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author wants you to use the chain rule. From the substitution $x = \ln(t)$, we get
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{1}{t}.$$
It follows that
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} =  \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} \frac{1}{t}.$$
The second derivative computation is similar; I'll leave it to you. The motivation for the substitution is to remove the non-constant coefficients in the derivative terms. This is a common trend in finding closed form solutions for ODEs.

Comment: It's not a **nonlinearity**: the Euler equation is as linear as they come.   What it removes is the presence of non-constant coefficients.

Comment: Ah sorry I misread the independent and dependent variables.

Comment: So the point is to get the Euler equation into the form t^2 + at  + b = 0 so I can use the $y = e^{rt}$ substitution and solve for r?

Comment: Yes, this is immediate when you get it in the form that looks like equation (iii).